# RadAjaxManager with RadCombobox ,very slow performance

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

Im using  page with RadAjaxManager and RadComboBox on it.

```
 <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" 
    DefaultLoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" EnablePageHeadUpdate="False">
     <AjaxSettings>
         <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="_Partners" >
             <UpdatedControls>
                 <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="_SubPartners" />
                 <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="_Clients" />
                 <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="_Positions" />
                 <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="_Candidates" />
             </UpdatedControls>
         </telerik:AjaxSetting>

         <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="_Candidates">
             <UpdatedControls>
                 <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rpCandidateApplications" />
             </UpdatedControls>
         </telerik:AjaxSetting>

         <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="_SubPartners">
             <UpdatedControls>
                 <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="_Clients" />
                 <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="_Candidates" />
                 <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="_Positions" />
             </UpdatedControls>
         </telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

I have large data binding , but it loads data very slow and my client is complnaing about performance.Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options for how to bind the items to the object, but the method I tend to use for large data sets is to "load on demand". The Telerik `RadComboBox` has a property called `EnableLoadOnDemand` when set to `true` this will get the next set of data. Looking at the network profiler you will see that small requests are made to the server to get the data required to populate the drop down.

Example:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlOptions" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:WebsiteData %>'
    SelectCommand="uspGetOptions" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlOptions" runat="server"  Width="100%" AppendDataBoundItems="false"
    MaxHeight="100px" DataTextField="DisplayText" DataValueField="UniqueId" DataSourceID="sqlOptions"
    EnableAutomaticLoadOnDemand="true" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" AllowCustomText="false" Filter="None"
    ShowWhileLoading="true"  ItemsPerRequest="20" EnableVirtualScrolling="true" 
    LoadingMessage="Loading..." EmptyMessage=""  >
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

This method has the significant down side that you can't quickly set the `SelectedValue` and see the selected text, however telerik have come up with a solution which they have released with example code. (See: [Setting an initial value in RadComboBox while using Load on Demand](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/combobox/setting-an-initial-value-in-radcombobox-while-using-load-on-demand.aspx))